# OSGi with Eclipse: How to hide eclipse Bundles?

Tags: eclipse, autocomplete, eclipse-plugin, osgi, bundle

Using Eclipse for OSGi Development is great.

Eclipse comes with cool auto completion features, thats also very helpful in OSGi.

By default Eclipse will suggest Bundles/Packages that are not created by myself but are available in Eclipse.

[image]

So my Question is how can i avoid that ? I just want to have my own bundles in these suggestions or auto completions. Is this possible ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The set of visible bundles is controlled by the "target platform" that you define. By default, it points to self, so you see various bundles present in the Eclipse installation.

See Window -> Preferences -> Plug-in Development -> Target Platform